# Free backup software for Windows that can back up Google Drive

Tags: backup, google-drive

I have around 10Gb of data on my Google Drive on Windows 10, which I want backed up just in case something goes off in the Google Cloud. Google Drive by default nowadays presents the drive as a device (usually G:) but can also be configured to present the cloud contents as a file folder.

I've tried the free versions of Macrium Reflect, Veeam Agent for Windows and Cobian backup among others to backup this drive, preferably in an incremental manner. In all cases I've failed miserably, nothing is taken as a backup.

I presume that the GDrive app does some tinkering, perhaps via a driver for example, resulting its contents being invisible to the backup application. Has anyone encountered a solution, preferably free, that can actually backup the Google Drive contents?

Comment: Do you use mirror or stream mode in Google Drive software?

Comment: Mirroring mode IIRC. This a work rig, I'm almost certain I made this configuration change. Strange thing is that according to the app, when one switches to mirroring mode then access to the Gdrive files are made over a designated folder, in contrast to streaming mode whereas access is made over either a virtual drive or a designated folder. But at home where I have mirroring mode enabled, access is made over the virtual drive (which should not be an option).

Comment: @Robert you were correct: on that specific system streaming mode was set up. After switching to mirroring mode everything works like a charm. Feel free to add it as an answer, I'll happily upvote it.